# How can I generate QR code in UWP application?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have tried to install QrCode.net nugget package for an UWP application, but it writes the error for me:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

are not not exists.

Does anyone know any nugget package for UWP application that helps me to create and show a QR code that generated from a string? (UWP/C#)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone know any nugget package for UWP application that helps me to create and show a QR code that generated from a string? (UWP/C#)

Since you are developing an UWP app, you can use the [`Zxing.Net.Mobile`](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) package. After installed this package, to generate a barcode, you can refer to the following example:

```
<Image x:Name="qrcodeImg" Stretch="None" />
```

code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var write = new BarcodeWriter();
    write.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
    var wb = write.Write("BarCode Content");
    this.qrcodeImg.Source = wb;
}
```

Comment: I did try this approach but at last line I did get error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'`

Comment: You should probably cast it  'var wb = (write as ZXing.BarcodeWriterGeneric<WriteableBitmap>).Write(jsonItem);'

Comment: `System.Drawing` is not available in UWP (anymore?), the library is not updated and some of the code requires `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to be available.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do using the **MVVM pattern** (*based on Grace Feng's approach*)

**XAML**

```
<Image Source="{Binding QRImage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**Viewmodel**

```
// Property
public WriteableBitmap QRImage { get; set; }

// Function to call
private void SetQR()
{
    var options = new QrCodeEncodingOptions()
    {
        DisableECI = true,
        CharacterSet = "UTF-8",
        Width = 1000,
        Height = 1000
    };

    BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter();
    writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
    writer.Options = options;
    QRImage= writer.Write(SelectedEvent.GetQrString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2020 Answer

Another option is to use QRCoder. Some example setup from the [github](https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder).

```cs
QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("The text which should be encoded.", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
```

Comment: ZXing.Net is actively maintained, take a look at github (github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net) and nuget (nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net). A new version is on the way. Sometimes it is better to take a look at the original pages instead of a blog post from 2017.